# UIScrollView Direction RTL for Right to Left Languages

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Can we change the behavior of UIScrollView that it scrolls RTL content in it's reverse mode.

Comment: What do you mean? Scroll views scroll both ways anyway!

Comment: just an idea, I've to start placing the content (using addSubViews) inside UIViewScroller on the negative side (x-axis) to start with

Comment: try to follow this link https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
count = 6;

[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, 320, 480)];

[pageControl setNumberOfPages:count];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

for(int i=count-1; i>=0; i--) { //start adding content in reverse mode
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * (count - i - 1); //ar
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", i]]];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

//scroll to the last frame as it's the first page for RTL languages
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * (count - 1);
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO];
```

The page control also needs to be indicate the last dot as the first dot (or first page)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
// Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.pageControl.currentPage = (page % count);
}
```

Comment: What I'm more concerned now if apple would understand and approve the reversed behavior of UIScrollView and PageControl though it's completely logical and understandable for Right to Left Language (Arabic, Hebrew) speaking guys.

Comment: You are my life saver

Answer (score 36):

You can achieve it by rotating `UIScrollView` in Child views by 180 (Pi).

```
self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
subView.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of the solution but after way too many hours trying to solve this problem, this actually solved it. +1

Comment: This is a good solution in case you don't need scroll indication: it will be at the top in this case.

Comment: Swift equivalent:     scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi)); subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));

Comment: LIFE saver!! :)

Comment: Spent hours trying to fix UIScrollView with UIStackView on RTL languages with no luck. That's the only solution that worked properly.

Answer (score 4):

I try it for xCode 7 and iOS 9 work good.

```
[self._imagesScrollView  setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
```

Comment: this solution flips everything, including the text being backwards if labels are in the scroll view. kumarPv solution works nicely to fix this

Comment: Sure, its true, it just used with images.

Answer (score 2):

I m not sure if I understand the question correctly but I take it like this: You want to have a (let's say) horizontal UIScrollView where you can add elements from right to left and when the contents exceed the scroll view frame you want to be able to scroll to the left rather than to the right in order to see the last elements.

In this case you can do this. For every new element calculate the total width you need and set it as contentOffset:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.childView.frame.size.width,
                                      scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Above I have a childView where the elements are added. It is placed at the right most position inside the scrollView minus 1 element width. Every time an element is added call:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x + kElementWidth,0.0)];
```

which will offset everything to the left. Then:

```
self.videoQueueCollectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.childView.center.x + kElementWidth,
                                                   self.childView.center.y);
```

That will snap eveything back to where it was BUT with the contentOffset set to the left. Which means that you can now scroll to the right.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code for Swift 3

```
self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:-1,y: 1);
```

Comment: Also, the subView must be transformed

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting semanticContentAttribute

```
self.scrollView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it's very simple just use:

```
.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
```

modifier on the horizontal scroll view.

Comment: The question is about UIKit's UIScrollView. You should update your answer to make it clear you are referring to a SwiftUI View.