# how to change direction of scrolling in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view with fixed height .my scroll view, scrolls from left to right but I want to scroll from Right To Left . how can I achieve this?!

this is how I created my Horizontal scroll View:

I've scroll view leading and trailing align to parent, and height = 50, inside my scroll view there is a view with equal height and width to its parent, but the priority of equal width is low, so it can scroll horizontally!

[image: my scroll view Constrains]

[image: view inside the scroll view constrains]

[image: my viewcontroller in storyboard]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of this layout (with the constraints also showing)?

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided here -> [UIScrollview-direction-rtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140959/uiscrollview-direction-rtl-for-right-to-left-languages)

Comment: @ZeMoon I've got my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140959/uiscrollview-direction-rtl-for-right-to-left-languages, although I've added screen shot! thank u for your time

Comment: @AbishDangol thank you for your answer! that was the correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140959/uiscrollview-direction-rtl-for-right-to-left-languages)
I had to add these lines to my code in swift 4:

```
myScroll.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi);
subview.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi);
```

Comment: Or you could simply increased contentSize of scrollView with additional Width and no height.